# Cookie weirdness in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies, asp-classic

I have some code that saves the user's ID as a cookie. It works fine in production, but moving the code to IIS7, upgrading the vendor app behind my code, and moving the app to an app in IIS7 instead of just running Default Web breaks this cookie function in IE.

Unfortunately it's a Classic ASP app so I can't find a good way to post a working version. But here are the relevant pieces.

Synopsis:

1. when the user checks "remember me" and logs in, a temporary cookie
   is created
2. when the user authenticates, the temp cookie is "promoted" to a
   permanent one and temp is expired
3. when the user unchecks "remember me" both cookies are supposed to be
   expired

What appears to be happening (just in IE?) is that there are 2 cookies, and unchecking the box only touches one of them.

Here is the relevant code. Hope it helps :)

On the login form:

```
var MHOLI = Get_Cookie("MHOLI");
//Check if cookie has a value
if (MHOLI != null && MHOLI != "" && MHOLI != "null") {
    //Set login text
    $("#Login").val(MHOLI);
    //keep remember login checkbox checked
    $("#RemonlineID").attr('checked', true);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#Password").focus();
        }, 200);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    //test if cookies are enabled..
    Set_Cookie('test', 'testvalue', '/', '', '');
    //if cookies are disabled, disable the option to remember username
    if (!Get_Cookie('test')) {
        $('#RemonlineID').attr("disabled", true);
    }
});​
```

When the "remember me" checkbox is changed:

```
var loginForm = document.getElementById("loginForm");
if (!loginForm.RemonlineID.checked) {
    setCookie("MHOLI", null, null);
    setCookie("tmpMHOLI", null, null);
}​
```

When the login form is submitted, set a 1 day cookie if "remember me" checked:

```
if (loginForm.RemonlineID.checked) {
    setCookie("tmpMHOLI", loginForm.Login.value, 1);
}
else {
    setCookie("tmpMHOLI", null, null);
}​
```

The setCookie function. Yes, I see that `expstring` is there but never used :):

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expireDate = new Date()
    //set "expstring" to either future or past date, to set or delete cookie, respectively
    var expstring = (typeof days != "undefined") ? expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + parseInt(days)) : expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() - 5)
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; expires=" + expireDate.toGMTString();
}​
```

And then some VBScript once the user makes it into the application. I'm thinking that it is creating a second cookie instead of

```
if Request.Cookies("tmpMHOLI") <> "" then
  Response.Cookies("MHOLI") = Request.Cookies("tmpMHOLI")
  Response.Cookies("MHOLI").Expires = Date() + 365
  Response.Cookies("tmpMHOLI") = ""
end if​
```

Is there something different about how IE7/8/9 handle cookies that this would not work? Is there something about IIS7.5 that is creating a cookie that the client script can't touch?

Comment: Since you are already using jQuery, may I suggest (a) using jQuery's facilities to deal with the code in code blocks 2 & 3. There might be some weird cross-browser thing going on, and jQuery should be able to (is designed to) correct this. Also, (b), take a look at the jQuery Cookie Plugin. Again, it may fix some IE-specific tomfoolery.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying not to refactor too much, since I'm a team of 1 trying to get this working code to port over to a new environment.

Comment: Trust me, jQuery will make it easier, especially for a team of 1 (same deal with my projects).

Comment: See http://www.jsfiddle.net and post your example code there for others to examine.

Comment: can you also tell where you redirect the user after login? to https from http?

Comment: Thanks @danorton, normally I would but this one has the VBScript code that I thought was pretty important.

Comment: @zipizip - The users are not being redirected to https at this point (though they will be when this version gets into production)

Comment: Maybe add "; path=/" to the end of the cookie, in case it is being set on different paths - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: I don't know if you have already chekcd it but -> https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly , of course you can always try server side coding instead of depending on jquery.

Comment: Thanks @KevinHakanson that was part of what I did to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up refactoring my `setCookie()` function. I was not properly expiring the cookies because the date calculations were funky. The quirksmode `createCookie()` function worked correctly.

Also, I set the path on the cookie when I set it server-side. Somehow the paths were different for cookies set by the prelogin and post login pages. So then the client script couldnt override the server side cookie and vice versa. Explicitly setting the path fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there's some [weirdness with IE / IIS7](http://forums.iis.net/t/1150171.aspx) and underscores in domain names. Could this be affecting you?

Comment: No but it was on an internal server type of thing so not a fully qualified URL. But I did try fully qualified and that didn't help.